# My tire was slashed. Replaced the inner tube, but should I replace the tire as well?

Tags: tire, puncture, hybrid-bike

Talking about a hybrid bike.

As the title says my tire was slashed. It happened overnight and the cut is on the side, so I'm 99% sure it was slashed. I replaced the tube and have been riding without any further problems for a while now. However I still have a ~1.5cm cut in my outer tire. My question is whether I should be concerned and whether I should replace it?

Comment: Does the cut go all the way through for the full 1.5cm length, or is most of it shallower? Front or rear tyre? Does the tube show through the cut (a photo would be good)?

Comment: Rear tire. The cut goes all the way for the length. Will update with a photo in a few hours. IIRC you can see the tube a bit.

Comment: As you say it's the rear, I suggest you  [boot](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/59792/7309) it (improvised), ride cautiously and get a new tyre ASAP.  On the front I might  do that myself but would be reluctant to recommend it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already know the answer to this question.

Slashes in the sidewall tend to open up as the pressure from inner tube is pushing the tire further apart. If you're lucky you might escape with a simple pinch flat. More serious problems include:

- the inner tube pushing through the sidewall rubbing on the frame or fork causing the inner tube to burst like a balloon.
- the inner tube removing the bead of the tire

Either of these I wouldn't want to happen at speed.

Answer (score 1):

A corollary point - you need to find a way to protect your bike from damage while it is parked.  Overnight is many hours of time when your bike is exposed and there are few people around.

If you were in a rack, park it further away from where people walk.

If your bike was blocking someone else, don't.

If you had unwittingly taken "someone's spot" then simply use another parking slot.

Can you store your bike overnight inside, in a garage or lockup, or somewhere else more-secure ?