Can I use a vulcanized patch on the inside of a tire?
I recently pinched a new tire (second ride) including the casing on one side - it's maybe 3mm long a few mm above the bead. This is a set of MTB tires I intend to run at 30psi max with a tubeless setup.
I'm not sure if the material on the inside of the tire is appropriate for the vulcanizing solution to create the necessary bond as it does on a tube.
Can I use a vulcanizing patch kit on this hole, inside of the tire (not the tube)?

Possibly a duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/59792/can-i-patch-a-tire-not-a-tube-that-has-a-hole/

@Criggie similar question for sure. But IMO wrong answer was accepted for this question’s case. It’s definitely possible to patch up an MTB tire with a traditional patch. Not sure what to do besides up vote the other answers that hint at this.
https://www.pinkbike.com/news/video-tech-tuesday-3-quick-and-easy-ways-to-repair-a-tubeless-tire.html

There are even tyre patches designed for this exact purpose such as the Rema Tip-Top TT13. Should work with non-tubeless tyres as well.

I ended up using vulcanized patches on the inside of the tire, sanding as suggested by Warren Burton. I also used a vulcanized patch on the outside on the sidewall near the bead. They've all held well.
What I also did, before patching, and after some digging around on the 'net, was sew the holes closed with some sturdy thread. For the hole that was among the tire tread, I fashioned a patch with a small piece of inner tube (you've got to prep inner tube well with washing and sanding) and some E6000 glue. It's held incredibly well and you'd have to look real close to even tell it's there.
So far so good! I probably could have skipped the patches on the inside and relied on tubeless sealant. I'll be doing this from now on to keep tires going.

Possibly yes, though it sounds like the position of the hole may make that difficult. Also any inner coating on the tyre will need to be sanded away to let the vulcanising fluid react with the base rubber. My personal experience was that this wasn’t possible trailside.
As you are the one with both the tyre and the patch kit it would be more time efficient to try and see what happens.
An alternative is to take the tyre to an automotive tyre shop and ask them to do a patch. Again, assuming the cut isn’t too near the bead. This professional repair will bring the tyre back to as-new condition from an air leak perspective.
